# Sum of remainders of Arithmetic Progression

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I have a set of numbers in an Arithmetic Series, $a$, $a+b$, $a+2b$, $a+3b$,$\cdots$

What is the sum of the remainders of first "$n$" terms when the terms of the AS are divided by $n$?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (a+kb)=a\sum_{k=0}^n 1+b\sum_{k=0}^nk$$

Comment: That is a generic summation of an Arithmetic Series.  I do not understand how that helps with the summation of the mod of n for each term in that Series.

Comment: Remember that calculating something mod n is additive and multiplicative, so taking mod n for each term is the same as taking mod n for the sums. Now express the sums in terms of n.

Comment: Nitpick: must be up to $n-1$. Also, consider $1,4,7,10$. Each mod $4$ are: $1,0,3,2$, so sum is $6$. But summing to $22$ and then mod $4$ is $2$. No?

Comment: Exactly right.   a mod n + b mod n + c mod n is not the same as (a+b+c) mod n.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* In $a,a+b,a+2b,a+3b,\dots,a+(n-1)b$, pair the terms $a+kb$ and $a+(n-k)b$. If $n$ is odd, these two terms are different. If $n$ is even, these two terms can be equal.